# How to chain values and find groups in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `Dataframe` from Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'element_from':'A', 'element_to':'B'}, 
                   {'element_from':'A', 'element_to':'C'}, 
                   {'element_from':'D','element_to':'C'},
                   {'element_from':'G','element_to':'H'},
                   {'element_from':'H','element_to':'I'}])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  element_from element_to
0            A          B
1            A          C
2            D          C
3            G          H
4            H          I
```

It represents links between different elements. Elements can be indirectly linked thanks to intermediaries. For instance A and C are linked thanks to B.

In other words there would be groups of elements I would like to identify.

The result could be a new column identifying the groups like this:

```
  element_from element_to group
0            A          B    G1
1            A          C    G1
2            D          C    G1
3            G          H    G2
4            H          I    G2
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this in Pandas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `networkx`

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(df.element_from.append(df.element_to).unique())
G.add_edges_from(df.to_records(False))

groups = list(nx.algorithms.components.connected_components(G))
df["group"] = [groups.index(group) for element in df.element_from for group in groups if element in group]
```

**Output**

```
  element_from element_to  group
0            A          B      0
1            A          C      0
2            D          C      0
3            G          H      1
4            H          I      1
```

---

To get the expected output add the following line:

```
df["group"] = 'G' + (df["group"] + 1).astype(str)

  element_from element_to group
0            A          B    G1
1            A          C    G1
2            D          C    G1
3            G          H    G2
4            H          I    G2
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out networkx and connected components.

```
import networkx as nx

# create graph from edge list
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='element_from', target='element_to')

# find connected components and label the nodes
to_map = {x: f'G{k}' for k,v in enumerate(nx.connected_components(G), 1) 
                     for x in v
         }
```

Output;

```
  element_from element_to group
0            A          B    G1
1            A          C    G1
2            D          C    G1
3            G          H    G2
4            H          I    G2
df['group'] = df['element_from'].map(to_map)
```