# using lambda apply recursively till condition is met pandas

Tags: python, pandas, recursion, apply

I am working with the following dataframe and want to generate columns with 'grandchildren'.

```
              Parent                         Child
0              plant                        cactus
1              plant                         algae
2              plant                tropical_plant
3             cactus                     aloe_vera
4              algae                   green_algae
5     tropical_plant                     monstrera
6             cactus                   blue_cactus
7          monstrera              monkey_monstrera
8        blue_cactus             light_blue_cactus
9  light_blue_cactus  desert_blue_cactus_lightblue
```

I want my final dataframe to look like this:

```
plant | cactus | aloe vera
plant | cactus | blue cactus | light blue cactus | desert_blue_cactus_lightblue
plant | algea | green_algea
plant | tropical_plant | monstrera | monkey monstrera
```

I have gotten more and more confused about what is the cleanest way to do this in pandas. I wrote a function to extract 'grandchildren' and want to apply this to the last column of the df till the condition is met that there are no grandchildren left. The main question is what the best way of doing this would be. I am currently facing the following issues:

1. I wrote a function find_grandchild(string), returning pandas.core.series.Series. If I use this function in apply, applying it to the last column of every row, I get a very strange result. I adjusted the function (below: find_grandchild_list(string) returning a list. Applying the new function to every row yields the result I want, but my column values are lists of lists. Since my function returns a list, I do not understand when and why these lists got wrapped in another list layer and how to rewrite my code to avoid this.
2. Considering that some parents have more than one child (cactus:aloe vera, cactus:blue_cactus), I need to explode the new column after applying find_grandchild and before returning to the condition. Intuitively, I would do this in a while loop, but I am wondering if this is a bad practice as well, see code sketch below.

```py
data = {'Parent':['plant','plant','plant','cactus','algae','tropical plant','cactus','monstrera','blue_cactus','light_blue_cactus']
        'Child': ['cactus','algae','tropical_plant','aloe_vera','green_algae','monstrera','blue_cactus','monkey_monstrera','light_blue_cactus','desert_blue_cactus_lightblue']}         
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
def find_grandchild(row):
    grandchild_value = df.iloc[:,0] == row
    return df[grandchild_value].iloc[:,-1]
        
def find_grandchild_list(row):
    grandchild_value = df.iloc[:,0] == row
    return [df[grandchild_value].iloc[:,-1]]
        
df.apply(lambda row : find_grandchild(row.iloc[-1]), axis=1)
        
df.apply(lambda row : find_grandchild_list(row.iloc[-1]), axis=1)
```

While sketch:

```py
while any(df.iloc[:,-1].isin(df.iloc[:,-2])):
    df = df.apply(lambda row : find_grandchild_list(row.iloc[-1]), axis=1) #currently not working bc of list problem
    df = df.explode(iloc[:,-1])
```

Comment: Is there a typo in your input data (algie instead of algae)? also in your code, you have the find_grandchild_list function twice, there is no difference.

Comment: Can you please post the find_granchild function?

Comment: fixed the typo and added find_grandchild()

Comment: Didn't find a way to solve it properly but I think that could be a good approach, maybe you find a way. check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66602465/how-to-chain-values-and-find-groups-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a graph problem that you can solve with [`networkx`](https://networkx.org).

Here is your graph:

[image]

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Parent', target='Child',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# find root
root =  next(nx.topological_sort(G))

# find terminal nodes (also possible with networkx)
leafs = df.loc[~df['Child'].isin(df['Parent']), 'Child']

# generate all paths from root to terminal nodes
out = pd.DataFrame([nx.shortest_path(G, root, l) for l in leafs])
```

output:

```
       0               1            2                  3                             4
0  plant          cactus    aloe_vera               None                          None
1  plant           algae  green_algae               None                          None
2  plant  tropical_plant    monstrera   monkey_monstrera                          None
3  plant          cactus  blue_cactus  light_blue_cactus  desert_blue_cactus_lightblue
```

Comment: One more follow up question, how would this work if you have multiple 'roots', let's say categories like 'trees', ' animals'  and ' rocks' in column 0 and their children in column[1]?

Comment: @e_mauritius it might be worth opening a follow-up question with a detailed example ;)